# Why does vector.erase() run into SIGABRT?

Tags: c++, string, vector, sigabrt, erase

My filepath normalization function has a weird issue I'm not fully understanding and am having trouble fixing (I'm also not very seasoned in C++).

```
/**
 * Converts any path (e.g. /a/d/../b/.//c/) to absolute /a/b/c format.
 * @param path Any valid path beginning with /
 * @return Path in absolute /a/b/c format.
 */
static std::string normalizePath(std::string path)
{
    if (path == "/")
        return "/";

    if (path[0] != '/') // full relative paths not supported due to lack of context
        return "";

    std::vector<std::string> segments = strsplit(path, '/');
    while (segments[0] == "." || segments[0] == "..")
        segments.erase(segments.begin());

    for (int i = 0; i < segments.size(); i++)
    {
        if (segments[i] == "." || segments[i].empty())
            segments.erase(segments.begin() + (i--));
        else if (segments[i] == "..")
            segments.erase(segments.begin() + (--i), segments.begin() + (i+2)); // SIGABRT
    }

    std::string r;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments.size(); i++)
        r += "/" + segments[i];

    return r;
}
```

It works fine with most inputs, but the input `"/a/.."` (which is supposed to return `"/"`) makes it crash with `SIGABRT` at the indicated line.

My understanding is I'm deleting the current and previous element, but apparently that assumption is wrong.

I'm also reluctant to just use `realpath()` because I'm working with virtual paths and I definitely don't want any calls to any filesystem.

Why does my code crash?
How do I make it work as intended?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: Using `--i` and `i+2` in the same statement is asking for trouble. Not to mention that `i+2` might be out of range and that the order of evaluation of function parameters are unspecified.

Comment: @user0042 std::remove seems to be for removing elements with a specific value, but I want to remove elements with a specific index.

Comment: The order of evaluation of function arguments are implementation defined.  Your example, modifies `i` in one argument, and accesses it in another, but the order of those two evaluations is implementation defined.  The result can be an invalid range (e.g. the end iterator not reachable from the start) depending on order or evaluation.   `vector::erase` has undefined behaviour if given an invalid range.   Solution:  decrement `i` in a separate statement, to avoid such concerns with side effects.

Comment: @Cobra - No you don't want to remove a specific index, you want to remove the values `"."`, `".."`, and `""`. Write a test for that (function or functor) and use the UnaryPredicate version [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: @BoPersson that's not the whole truth. If I remove a `".."` I also want to remove whatever came immediately before it. As far as I'm understanding things `std::remove` can't do that.

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging this?  I'd expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB.  Please [edit] your question to summarize what the debugging tools told you and why they didn't solve your problem.  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has undefined behavior, because it accesses `i` twice in the context where the accesses are unsequenced with respect to each other:

```
segments.erase(segments.begin() + (--i), segments.begin() + (i+2));
```

Since the order of evaluation is unspecified, and the order of applying side effects is unknown, `segments.begin() + (i+2)` could evaluate to an iterator past vector's end.

You can fix this by using the value of `i` without pre-decrement, and applying `--` after returning from `erase`:

```
else if (segments[i] == "..") {
    segments.erase(std::next(segments.begin(), i-1), std::next(segments.begin(), i+1));
    --i;
}
```

**Note:** The above code uses [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) instead of adding numbers to iterators.